# Tkinter only prints empty strings

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create a GUI with tkinter to print a string entered in the entry box. I have written the following code

```
import tkinter as tk
top= tk.Tk()

labelAmount=tk.Label(text='Amount')
Amount= tk.Entry()
amount=Amount.get()

Add = tk.Button(top, text='Add', command = lambda : print(amount))

Add.pack()
Amount.pack()
labelAmount.pack()

top.mainloop()
```

The problem is that when I am pressing the 'Add' button, an empty string is being printed.
It would be great if someone can help me with this problem.

Comment: `amount=Amount.get()` You are calling this in the wrong place. It should be inside the button handler: `Add = tk.Button(top, text='Add', command = lambda : print(Amount.get()))`

Comment: Statements execute in order. So you're assigning to `amount` immediately after you create the entry, not after the user types something into it.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Thanks for the suggestion! It is working properly now.